# How to add audio to an existing video without creating a new video in Android

Tags: android, mp4

I want to make a **dubbing app**. I will get audio from `user's microphone`. I have a **mp4 video**. I want to override *user's audio to mp4 video*. How can i do this?
I searched a lot and i think **mp4 parser** library will help me but it is very hard to understand me.
I didn't find a good example for this.
Is there anyone to explain to me clearly?

Comment: Sorry !!! But the stackoverflow is not the tools recommendation site.

Comment: @psyco this is correct question, probably you just don't understand it.
one of my team members did smth like that last year i'll try to find a gist

Comment: @Stepango. You are right. But as i told you this doesn't meet the policy of stackoverflow which is why it has been put on hold by **Martijin**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your **MP4** has been encoded by h.264 , you can easily use **MP4parser.**

```
try {
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
H264TrackImpl h264Track = new H264TrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl(baseDir + "/video.h264"));
AACTrackImpl aacTrack = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl( baseDir + "/aac_sample.aac" ));

Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.addTrack(h264Track);
movie.addTrack(aacTrack);
Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);

FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream(new File(baseDir +"/output.mp4")).getChannel();
mp4file.writeContainer(fc);
fc.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Not Tested. May it help.

Comment: You can do this by using media muxer android 4.3 api.    https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html

Comment: The solution of `mp4parser` doesn't seem to work for me. It keeps crashing with exception: `E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.profiler"
2019-02-18 16:06:05.148 13172-13492/com.lb.videoandaudiojointest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.lb.videoandaudiojointest, PID: 13172
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=0 out of bounds (limit=0)` . Can you please show full code of how to use the normal API ?